# Stuck in summation of vectors in clojure without using map

Tags: recursion, clojure, sum

I am trying to print sum of 2 vectors without using `map`. My code is

```
  (defn sumv [a1 b1]
    (if (or (empty? a1) (empty? b1))
     (list )   
       (list (+ (first a1) (first b1))
         (sumv (rest a1) (rest b1))
          )))
```

When providing:

```
(sumv [9 6 5 65 43 21 67] [0 0 0])
```

The output I am getting is:

```
(10 (8 (8 ())))
```

But I want:

```
(10 8 8)
```

Can anybody suggest me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Why are you giving negative points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your recursion is nesting a new list in each iteration.

When you're doing

```
(list (+ a b) (sumv (rest x) (rest y))
```

It will expand as

```
(list (+ a b) (list (+ c d) (sumv (rest z) (rest w)))
```

So at the end what you have is something like this:

```
 user> (list 2 (list 3 (list 4)))
   => (2 (3 (4)))
```

There is a fast alternative and it's to call `flatten` on your final result:

```
 user> (flatten (list 2 (list 3 (list 4))))
   => (2 3 4)
```

But you can always change the recursion building the correct list from the beginning.

For instance using `cons` on the recursion step:

```
 (cons (+ a b) (sumv (rest x) (rest y))
```

In each step you `cons` an element to a single list, for you to visualize the recursion:

```
 user> (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 [])))
 (2 3 4)
```